# What does this backslash notation mean?

Tags: notation, logarithms

I am doing a MOOC online and have no idea what the backslash set notation means. Can anyone help?
$$2^{\sqrt {\log n}}$$
[image]

Comment: Looks like MathJax or LaTeX  tags.

Comment: Is is a command, for LaTeX and similar TeX languages. The "translation" is $2^{\sqrt{\log(n)}}$.

Comment: Its just on Coursera

Comment: It's MathJax tags  It's intended to register as $2^{\sqrt{\log (n)}}$

Comment: If I write 2^\sqrt{\log(n)} and put dollar signs round it, I get $ 2^\sqrt{\log(n)}$. Good, isn't it!

Comment: It is denotes a command of MathJaX a javascript of a great language of LaTeX: but here your question is off-topic.

Comment: Ah come on. TeX reference was the third result when I [searched on google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=0yW&channel=fs&ei=luY_X6CJHcL0swWonZmIDw&q=%22%5Csqrt%22&oq=%22%5Csqrt%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIFCAAQkQIyBAgAEEMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BAgAEEc6CAgAEAcQChAeOgYIABAHEB5QodUCWKKJA2CTiwNoAHABeACAAawBiAGdCJIBAzEuN5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwigrPbhzKzrAhVC-qwKHahOBvEQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: The curly braces group what goes under the square root sign; they are not set notation

Answer (score 1):

This looks like TeX notation, which isn't rendered.
It should look like this:
$$
2^\sqrt{\log(n)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a software used to typeset mathematics called TeX. The syntax of TeX is such that you use the "\" character to indicate you're starting a mathematical symbol. In your example, the \sqrt{} indicates that everything in the curly braces will be placed under a radical. Note that the curly braces here do not indicate a set (in TeX you use { and } for sets), and are instead what TeX uses to delimit and group mathematics for typesetting.

The syntax "\log()" and "^" are also part of TeX, although the latter is much more common in general mathematics. Somewhat serendipitously, there is a form of TeX implemented in Math Stack Exchange and if you put such symbols between a pair of dollar signs such as

> \$\$ input here \$\$

you'll see your input typeset. For instance, $$ 2^\sqrt{\log(n)}.$$